# DotNetOpenAuth throwing an error in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, dotnetopenauth

I'm using a third party library to fetch a collection of items
The API is based on DotNetOpenAuth.

The api call to fetch data works fine when tested through a simple console application.

However, My goal is to use this API within a web service.
When I test my Web service, the same API call to fetch data throws an exception:

> "Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the
>   response."

and the error code is 500 .

I find it strange that the same API call works from a console app but not from a web service call. Help!

the webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Start with turning on logging change your config to <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

Comment: Hi, I wish I could , but the API is from a third party hosting :(

Comment: Actually to be more clear, I'm calling another service from my service .. and that other service is not in my control

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on.

1) in the API, I was requesting for paged results, and it does not  start with 0. It worked when I sent > 1 as the page offset.

2) I should have noticed that underneath this ambiguous error message, a server error code (500) was being returned . 90% of the time it means your sending crap to the server hehe.

problem solved!

Comment: But honestly, that message can really throw you offtrack !!